# Spring MVC forwarding to controller with different HTTP method

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have login controller methods like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    // do stuff with locale and model
    // return an html page with a login form
    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/account/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(Model model, /* username + password params */){
    try {
        // try to login
        // redirect to account profile page
        return "redirect:/account/profile";
    } catch (LoginException e) {
        // log
        // here I want to reload the page I was on but not with a url /account/login
        // possibly using a forward
        model.addAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
        return "forward:/home";
    }
}
```

The above code works on successful log-in attempt. However, it fails when the log-in attempt fails because Spring's `forward` uses the current request with the same HTTP method. So because I used a POST to send my username/password (which caused log-in to fail), the forward will also use POST to go to the handler method for `/home`, `home()`, which is expecting a GET.

Is there any way in Spring to redirect to another controller method with a different HTTP method **while maintaining the current model** (since I want to show the error message)?

This is on Spring 3.2.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `redirect` instead:

```
return "redirect:/home";
```

If you need `Model` attributes to be available after the redirect, you can use [flash attributes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes).

Comment: Redirect works for POST/REDIRECT/GET. Is there anything similar for POST/REDIRECT/POST or GET/REDIRECT/POST? Or any other method than GET in the last step?

Comment: The last step in your description is the GET to `/home`. This looks like a standard POST/REDIRECT/GET to me.

Comment: No it is, I'm just curious if you can do the opposite.

Comment: I believe a redirect always results in a GET, so no.